# Setup virtual path with .NET Core Kestrel and Node

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, kestrel-http-server

Is it possible to setup a .NET Core project on localhost:5000 and another Node project which runs next to the previous one, but at localhost:5000/api?

I have done this with .NET 4.6 and IISExpress, but a lot have changed with Kestrel server and I don't understand how to do it.

**An image of how I did earlier**
[image]
Adding the path then clicking Create Virtual Directory.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Only a single process can open that port. Or perhaps I am not understanding your question because you said you have done it before.

Comment: Yes, I did this with IISExpress. The second project ran as a virtual path to localhost:5000 but on another absolut url.

Comment: Was the other URL on the same port? Are you just talking about an alias?

Comment: Yeah, both on same port. Ill provide an image of how i did it in IISExpress.

Comment: var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:5001","http://localhost:5001/api")
                .Build();

You see the part about UseUrls is what you mean?

Comment: Yes! But should host different apps. Now both those are running on one project?

Comment: I see what you are saying. Since IIS Express ran both web apps is controlled the connections but now you are using Kestrel so you need the ability to run two web apps from the process.

Comment: Yes, correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with kestrel alone. Check out the article explaining the architecture of developing with kestrel versus traditional IIS

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS